# Braintree—how do I get the last_4 credit card details from a transaction OR subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, credit-card, braintree

From the `result` of a `Transaction.sale()` OR a `Subscription.create()`, how do I access the credit card details in the payment?

I have the following methods:

```
  def bt_make_customer(donation, nonce)
    result = Braintree::Customer.create(
      first_name: donation.user.first_name,
      last_name: donation.user.last_name,
      email: donation.user.email,
      payment_method_nonce: nonce
      )
  end

  def bt_make_payment(donation, customer, nonce)
    if donation.type == "ReoccurringDonation"
      result = Braintree::Subscription.create(
        payment_method_token: customer.payment_methods[0].token,
        price: donation.amount,
        plan_id: "pay-monthly"
        )
    elsif donation.type == "SingleDonation"
      result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        :amount => donation.amount,
        :payment_method_nonce => nonce,
        :options => {:submit_for_settlement => true}
        )
    end
  end
```

As you can see, the program accepts one-time donations, or monthly subscriptions. When either is made, I want to get the credit card details such as last_4 to display in a custom receipt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the credit card fields, you need to type

```
result.transaction.credit_card_details.{field you want}
```

You can pause the program with `byebug` after the transaction, and type `result.inspect` in your console to see what fields the result contains.

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
result.last_4
```

for getting The last 4 digits of the credit card number.
 For more help visit [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card/ruby#last_4)

Comment: I'm getting `NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'last_4' for #<Braintree::SuccessfulResult:0x007fd7b1193a80>`